# Play and hang out

Tags: non-native-english

I noticed a lot of Asian people use the word "play" when they want to say "I'm hanging out".. Like this one friend said she was playing with her friends. And sent me a picture of them drinking and eating. So it was a bit confusing. Why do they tend to use "play" instead of "hang out" or spending time or a more related word?

Comment: Perhaps the contrast is *play* vs *work*. What did your friend say about her choice of words?

Comment: Are you asking why "a lot of Asian people" use *play* in such contexts? Why do you think someone would be able to answer that, if it were true? Define "more related word". Unclear question, showing no research.

Comment: I dunno. Somewhere they got the idea that they can use *play* with that meaning. Maybe from Oxford dictionary? "Engage in activity for enjoyment and recreation rather than a serious or practical purpose". True, native speakers that I know don't use play in that context,  but the definition seems to license it.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *Asian*? The "default" Asian in South Asian in Britain but East Asian in the U.S., and in theory the term could include Israelis, Maldivians, Uzbeks, and Ainu, who are unlikely to share patterns of English usage.